# Optimizing EI in the TPE algorithm

Tags: probability, hyperparameter, bayesian-optimization

My question refers to the section "4.1 Optimizing EI in the TPE algorithm" on page 4 of the paper *Algorithms for Hyperparameter Optimization* (https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2011/file/86e8f7ab32cfd12577bc2619bc635690-Paper.pdf).

The authors provide the following step, where $\gamma := p(y < y^*)$:

$$\ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} (y^* - y) p(y)dy = \gamma y^* \ell(x) - \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*}p(y)dy$$

However, this is where I arrive:

\begin{align}
\ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} (y^* - y) p(y)dy  
&= \left[ \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y^* p(y)dy \right] - \left[ \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y  p(y)dy \right]\\   
&= \left[y^* \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} p(y)dy \right] - \left[ \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y  p(y)dy \right]\\
&= y^* \ell(x) p(y < y ^*)  - \left[ \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y  p(y)dy \right]\\
&=  y^* \ell(x) \gamma - \left[ \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y  p(y)dy \right]\\   
&= \gamma  y^* \ell(x) - \ell(x) \int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y  p(y)dy \\  
\end{align}

The difference between my result and the authors' result is that I still have a $y$ in the remaining integral. I got $\int_{-\infty}^{y^*} y  p(y)dy$ but the authors got $\int_{-\infty}^{y^*}p(y)dy$. Do you know how to explain this? Your tips would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That's a typo, it should indeed be $\gamma y^{*} \ell(x) - \ell(x)\int_{-\infty}^{y^*}y p(y) dy$ as you pointed out.

The reason this works is because the derivation can actually continue from the previous expression
$\ell(x)\int_{-\infty}^{y^*}(y^*-y)p(y)dy$ as follows:

Let $$I := \int_{-\infty}^{y^*}(y^*-y)p(y)dy$$

Noting that $I$ doesn't depend on $x$.

Now substitute to get
\begin{align*}
EI_{y^*}(x)
&= \frac{\ell(x)I}{\gamma\ell(x) + (1-\gamma)g(x)} \\
&= I \times \frac{1}{\gamma + (1-\gamma)\frac{g(x)}{\ell(x)}} \\
&= I \times \left(\gamma + (1-\gamma)\frac{g(x)}{\ell(x)}\right)^{-1}
\end{align*}
Since $I$ does not depend on $x$ it suffices to simply evaluate $\left(\gamma + (1-\gamma)\frac{g(x)}{\ell(x)}\right)^{-1}$ in order to determine the next candidate point to evaluate the fitness function.